# How to transform this php associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, associative-array

I have this php associative input array.

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Data' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'type_id' => '1',
            'data_value' => '35.5000'
        ),
        'Type' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Temperature'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Data' => array(
            'id' => '11',
            'type_id' => '1',
            'data_value' => '33.7000'
        ),
        'Type' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Temperature'
        )
    )
```

I want to convert it to this output array;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'v' => (int) 1
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'v' => '35.5000'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'v' => (int) 2
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'v' => '33.7000'
        )
    )
```

The element data_value is extracted from the input array into the output array.

The code I have written looks like this;

```
                $data2 = array();
                foreach ($InputArray as $key=>$value)
                {
                    $data2[] = array(
                                array(                                        
                                    array('v' => $key),
                                    array('v' => $value['Data']['data_value']) 
                            )
                        );
                }
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. The output from this code looks like this;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            )
        )
    )
```

What did I do wrong? Why do I get the error "maximum depth reached"? How can I retrieve the desired output array? I am actually doing this in cakephp.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what v=>1 and v=>2 in your output array are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one wrapping `array()` to many:

```
        $data2 = array();
        foreach ($InputArray as $key=>$value)
        {
            $data2[] = array(                                      
                            array('v' => $key),
                            array('v' => $value['Data']['data_value']) 

                );
        }
```

You can see this working [here](http://ideone.com/K2djnG). It is good use to prepare your code in services like [ideome](http://ideone.com/) or [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) in order to make it easier for people to help you with debugging.

Comment: Amazing! How did you catch my mistake so quickly? Thanks but you made me feel like an idiot:)

Comment: @user3293156 consider accepting my answer thus marking this question as answered thus preventing this question from getting more attention thus keeping others from reading about you feeling like an idiot ;-)

Comment: Of course. I have been trying to accept the answer a few times already. Stack Overflow only allows me to accept in 5 minutes time from now.

Comment: @user3293156 Well, take those 5 minutes and check out the services i mentioned in my edit. They might help you in the future, either for asking or for answering questions. Or just to play with them :D

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the problem is related to a setting for PHP http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.max_depth . Could you check with your hosting provider?

Comment: That would only solve the problem of displaying the result, not the fact that the result is wrong :-/

Comment: @Andresch Serj you had answered in right way, no need to duplicate 100500 times same answer. I just add 'why **maximum depth reached** happens'. ;)